# SFML error from loadFromFile Absolute path

Tags: c, sfml

```cpp
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(600,600), "sfml work");//윈도우 명령어 지칭하는 대상의 이름이 window라고 하는거다. 
    sf::Sprite background;
    sf::Texture texture;    
    
    if (!texture.loadFromFile("firepunch.png"))
    {
        std::cout<< "ERROR" << std::endl;
    }

    background.setTexture(texture);

    while (window.isOpen()) //만약 윈도우창이 열린다면
    {
        sf::Event ss; // Event는 명령어 이벤트 이름이 ss라고 하는거다 명령어+명령어 이름 순인듯
        
        while (window.pollEvent(ss))
        {
            switch (ss.type)
            {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                window.close();
                break;

            case sf::Event::Resized:
                    sf::FloatRect visibleArea(0, 0, ss.size.width, ss.size.height);
                    window.setView(sf::View(visibleArea));
                    break;
            }
        }
        window.clear();
        window.draw(background);
        window.display();

    }
    return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgNCu.png)

I am beginner of sfml when write this code debuger says this code have excess error. I think "if (!texture.loadFromFile("firepunch.png"))" is error but i can fix it 3 hours. search a google but can't find the solution. this error says 'while read 0xC0000005: 0x00000000 An access violation has occurred.' please help me.... what can i do?

Comment: I have tried your code and it works fine. So it must be either: 1) "firepuch.png" is not found (in which case you should see the error msg), 2) There is something wrong with your computer or SFML version 3) There is something wrong with the image file that you have (maybe try another one?)